# Google Analytics Embed API demo not showing at all

Tags: google-analytics

I am replicating Google Analytics Embed API demos, which you can find [here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/). So far, I have been able to replicate the basic dashboard, multiple date ranges, multiple views and interactive charts using my clientid
The one that is giving me trouble is the Third Party Visualizations and I am following the steps according to what is posted.
By the way for step 3 I am using the full path "https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/..."
Once I log in with my Google Account, all I get is the embed-api-auth-container but not the charts. I am using the following code:
(Apologies, I am new to StackOverflow)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Thirtd Party Visualizations</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/css/main.css" />
<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>
<div id="active-users-container"></div>
<div id="chart-1-container"></div>
<div id="legend-1-container"></div>
<div id="chart-2-container"></div>
<div id="legend-2-container"></div>
<div id="chart-3-container"></div>
<div id="legend-3-container"></div>
<div id="chart-4-container"></div>
<div id="legend-4-container"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/view-selector2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/date-range-selector.js"></script>
<script src="https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/active-users.js"></script>


<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'XXXX',
  });

  var activeUsers = new gapi.analytics.ext.ActiveUsers({
    container: 'active-users-container',
    pollingInterval: 5
  });

  activeUsers.once('success', function() {
    var element = this.container.firstChild;
    var timeout;

    this.on('change', function(data) {
      var element = this.container.firstChild;
      var animationClass = data.delta > 0 ? 'is-increasing' : 'is-decreasing';
      element.className += (' ' + animationClass);

      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        element.className =
            element.className.replace(/ is-(increasing|decreasing)/g, '');
      }, 3000);
    });
  });

  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ext.ViewSelector2({
    container: 'view-selector-container',
  })
  .execute();

  viewSelector.on('viewChange', function(data) {
    var title = document.getElementById('view-name');
    title.innerHTML = data.property.name + ' (' + data.view.name + ')';

    activeUsers.set(data).execute();

    renderWeekOverWeekChart(data.ids);
    renderYearOverYearChart(data.ids);
    renderTopBrowsersChart(data.ids);
    renderTopCountriesChart(data.ids);
  });


  function renderWeekOverWeekChart(ids) {

    // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
    var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

    var thisWeek = query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    var lastWeek = query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:nthDay',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(0).subtract(1, 'week')
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'end-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'day').day(6).subtract(1, 'week')
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    Promise.all([thisWeek, lastWeek]).then(function(results) {

      var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
      var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
      var labels = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[0]; });

      labels = labels.map(function(label) {
        return moment(label, 'YYYYMMDD').format('ddd');
      });

      var data = {
        labels : labels,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Last Week',
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : data2
          },
          {
            label: 'This Week',
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : data1
          }
        ]
      };

      new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-1-container')).Line(data);
      generateLegend('legend-1-container', data.datasets);
    });
  }


  function renderYearOverYearChart(ids) {

    // Adjust `now` to experiment with different days, for testing only...
    var now = moment(); // .subtract(3, 'day');

    var thisYear = query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
      'metrics': 'ga:users',
      'start-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    var lastYear = query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:month,ga:nthMonth',
      'metrics': 'ga:users',
      'start-date': moment(now).subtract(1, 'year').date(1).month(0)
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      'end-date': moment(now).date(1).month(0).subtract(1, 'day')
          .format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    });

    Promise.all([thisYear, lastYear]).then(function(results) {
      var data1 = results[0].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
      var data2 = results[1].rows.map(function(row) { return +row[2]; });
      var labels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                    'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

      for (var i = 0, len = labels.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (data1[i] === undefined) data1[i] = null;
        if (data2[i] === undefined) data2[i] = null;
      }

      var data = {
        labels : labels,
        datasets : [
          {
            label: 'Last Year',
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : data2
          },
          {
            label: 'This Year',
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : data1
          }
        ]
      };

      new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-2-container')).Bar(data);
      generateLegend('legend-2-container', data.datasets);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err.stack);
    })
  }


  function renderTopBrowsersChart(ids) {

    query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
      'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
      'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
      'max-results': 5
    })
    .then(function(response) {

      var data = [];
      var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

      response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
        data.push({ value: +row[1], color: colors[i], label: row[0] });
      });

      new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-3-container')).Doughnut(data);
      generateLegend('legend-3-container', data);
    });
  }


  function renderTopCountriesChart(ids) {
    query({
      'ids': ids,
      'dimensions': 'ga:country',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'sort': '-ga:sessions',
      'max-results': 5
    })
    .then(function(response) {

      var data = [];
      var colors = ['#4D5360','#949FB1','#D4CCC5','#E2EAE9','#F7464A'];

      response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
        data.push({
          label: row[0],
          value: +row[1],
          color: colors[i]
        });
      });

      new Chart(makeCanvas('chart-4-container')).Doughnut(data);
      generateLegend('legend-4-container', data);
    });
  }

  function query(params) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({query: params});
      data.once('success', function(response) { resolve(response); })
          .once('error', function(response) { reject(response); })
          .execute();
    });
  }

  function makeCanvas(id) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    container.innerHTML = '';
    canvas.width = container.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = container.offsetHeight;
    container.appendChild(canvas);

    return ctx;
  }

  function generateLegend(id, items) {
    var legend = document.getElementById(id);
    legend.innerHTML = items.map(function(item) {
      var color = item.color || item.fillColor;
      var label = item.label;
      return '<li><i style="background:' + color + '"></i>' + label + '</li>';
    }).join('');
  }

  Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
  Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = 'easeInOutQuart';
  Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
  Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;

});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code you linked to is missing some elements and needs to be updated.

Check out this bug on Github which has a workaround and allows you to track the progress of the fix:
https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/issues/51